# Spark T4 templates for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, spark-view-engine

I was just curious if any Spark T4 templates already exist that match/are similar to the out of the box web forms view templates (create, edit, details, etc...). My Google skills didn't lead me to any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've translated the mvc2 templates to spark, feel free to copy:

http://guiftp.free.fr/SparkViewTemplates.rar

Answer (score 2):

T4MVC should work fine with Spark.  Here is a related [forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1497350.aspx).  That being said, I'm not clear from your initial post that T4MVC is the kind of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I meant this part of comment ! if it helps...

#  re: T4MVC 2.5.01: added support for Html.RenderAction and Html.Action

@spark_guy: I haven't played extensively with the Spark view engine, but I think that T4MVC should work with it just as well as it works with the aspx view engine.  If you hit specific issues, please let me know.

YOu can find all the T4MVC posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/tags/T4MVC/, though ideally there would be a single posts that describes it all in one place (I'll try to do this).  Note that if you download T4MVC, the readme has good 'getting started' info that tells you what it's all about.